# Why isn't Xcode (Swift 3) flagging APIs from iOS 10+ when deployment target is 9.3?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

The title covers it. Latest Xcode and using Swift 3. I'm probably using some stuff from 10+, but no messages, and then crashes on an iOS 9.3.5 system. My understanding is that the compiler would flag any APIs that weren't appropriate for the deployment target. Is there a setting I missed? Am I wrong in believing the compiler will flag offending APIs?

Most other questions about deployment targets seem to be pre-Swift 2, and the later ones seem to say they should be flagged.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you set up your "iOS Deployment Target" to iOS 9.3 on the Project settings? (Also make sure that the Settings inside the Target Deployment Target is either grayed out or specified to iOS 9.3)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. iOS Deployment Target for Target is 9.3 and same for Project settings. Any reason to change Base SDK from Latest iOS 10.2? Uncertain what else to try.

Comment: What stuff from iOS 10 are you using? How do you know that is the issue?

Comment: I don't know that I'm hitting code from 10, Mike. It's just a suspicion, as it's one of the few unique elements of the user's setup (app works on their other devices, which are 10+). That started search for 10-specific code, which lead to this question. There are so many API references that it would take eons to hand-check all of them. I found one or two quickly manually (UIActivity related), but they weren't in code referenced by user. Hoping that Xcode can identify others so I can verify or eliminate it as the source of trouble.

Comment: So you don't know for sure that you're calling iOS-only API? So now I have a question: what's the crash message? Do you have a symbolicated crash log? Otherwise it's impossible to help you.

Comment: I'm working through the crash log. Just got delivered with few hour delay from crash. First time dealing with tester crash (lucky, I guess?) so trying to figure it all out. Will also insert a specific 10+ API call to see how compiler responds. Yes, I assumed the issue was likely related to API vs Deployment Target be/c that was the only unique difference I could identify. I certainly could be wrong on that, and am trying to narrow the possibilities. Examining deployment target seemed like a good idea regardless.

Comment: Three observations. 1. I added a specific iOS 10+ reference: `let x = self.bounds.customMirror`. It was not flagged by the compiler. It also ran fine on a 9.3 simulator (I checked a property of x). That confuse me. 2. In Apple's list of 9.3 -> 10 changes, it marks CGRect.midX (among others) as removed. Compiler doesn't flag it. I use this without problem on 9.3 and 10+. That also confuses me. And 3, I now think my underlying problem is not related to deployment target. Posted details at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42443976/what-does-this-swift-ipad-crash-log-mean

Comment: The underlying problem is solved, with the solution being in the link posted in the comment above. It IS 9.x related, but not in the way I first thought. Turns out it's a known...bug, I guess, or 'feature'...and the solution is valid. Thanks to all for assistance with what became a circuitous route to an answer. I'm still uncertain of what is and isn't flagged, but that's not the most pressing issue in light of the discovered solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think Xcode swift compiler will only flag when you build against the selected iOS version. Try downloading iOS Simulator 9.3 and then select it and build. Deployment target doesn't cause any warning unless the current iOS version selected in the dropdown during build time doesn't support an API.

Comment: No, it warns and even marks it as error when using APIs that are lower than your current deployment target regardless of your simulators.

Comment: I appreciate your taking the time to answer, Tushar. Chiquis seems to be correct in that nothing changed with the 9.3 simulator. Interestingly, it didn't crash where tester's device seemed to. App ran fine on Simulator 9.3. This is confusing.